# PWM (Pulse Width Modulation) on Arduino using Python

Tags: python, arduino, pwm

I would like to know, if it is possible to do PWM on Arduino Board, with Python as the language. If yes, any light on the same would be really helpful.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you figured out the Python part yet?

Comment: That's what I'm asking. Is there any Arduino package we can install and run through Python?

Comment: Have you used Arduino yet?

Comment: Hi Ignacio,

Yes. I've used Arduino for a number of projects. The way I've been using Ard.. is through the Arduino IDE.

For a new project, I need to use Python as my scripting language, so my question to you is, Is it possible to program Arduino via the Python. If yes, how? Is there any particular package for Arduino in Python? 

I just need a few bits of information, and than I'm good to start. 

Thanks again for responding.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it´s not possible to run python code on arduino directly. You have to write some kind of firmware for the Arduino, so you can talk to the serialport through python running on a computer.
Normally that would be over the USB port...

It´s all described here:
[Arduino and Python](https://playground.arduino.cc/Interfacing/Python/)